# How to return a string value from sqlite query?

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my query. I want to get the string value and return the single value to the activity class from where I have called the `getSelectedMerchantCode` function. My code is not working. Its returning "error"

```
public String getSelectedMerchantCode(String merchantname){
            String selection = "Error";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT merchantCode FROM " + "merchantList"+ " WHERE " + "merchantName" + "='" + merchantname + "'", null);
            if(c.getCount() == 1){
                c.moveToFirst();
                selection = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("merchantCode"));
                return selection;
            }
            c.close();
            db.close();

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: what is the error ? post error log

Comment: Because i actually don't want the row ID. i want a specific code which is in the table according to the merchantName. @pskink

Comment: @GaneshGudghe there is no error. its returning the string "error" which i have declared in the code.

Comment: Yes. I have tried onItemClickListener. Its getting the selected name. Now i want the specific code of that selected name for which i don't knw what to do. I am now basically want to run a query, get the code, then insert it to a new table.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko "error" is just a string which i have declared in the fucntion.

Comment: try c.getString(0); you are selecting only merchant code, and checking if get Count() == 1 so there should be one record in return

Comment: have you tried debugging? Probably you have multiple rows in `merchantList` having same `merchantname`. And since you check only for `c.getCount() == 1` - it won't enter this if

Comment: @pskink yes i have tried. Its giving me rowID. But i don't need rowID.

Comment: could you post the 'error' log?

Comment: @Beasteca he said "error" is just hard coded string, check the code please

Comment: Try this query:   `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT merchantCode FROM " + "merchantList"+ " WHERE " + "merchantName" + " = '" + merchantname + "'", null);`

Comment: It's working now. I replcaed (c.getCount==1) to (c.moveToFirst)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
public List<String> getMyItems(String name) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT Item_Name FROM " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE Item_Name= " + name;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
           String name = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name")));

            stringList.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return stringList;
}
```